# Testng: Pass values from XML to Java class

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I'm doing testing using TesnNG. I have class of constants `Constant.java`:

```
public class Constants {   
    public static final String ID = "myID";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "support1";
    public static final String ENV = "stage";
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "000458";
```

Those parameters will different and depend on accounts and environments. Is it a way to use for example `Test.xml`:

```
<suite name="Regression">
<parameter name="asset" value="0"/>
<test name="Test3">
    <classes>
        <class name="UnTrusted.Login"/>
        <class name="NegativeLogin"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

and pass parameters from XML to `Constant.java` that will have values: `id`, `password`, `env`, `account#`.

I know you can pass parameters from XML to `@Test` using `@Parameters` but I'm not passing into `@Test` annotation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your constants are properties, not constants.  This implies that the values should be populated at run-time.

Comment: I did first them constant. Now requirements changed, I want populated them any time I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my thoughts..
1) You can instead create a simple `setter/getter` class.
2) Use `Unmarshalling` to convert `XML` to `JAVA`
3) Once you have the Object generated, you can set your `setter/getter` class with that generated object.

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly if you term it as a requirement change. You can modify your approach with the use of `DataProviders`.

// **In your data class XYZ** :

```
@DataProvider(name = "LoginData")
public static Object[][] dataProviderLogin(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
    String testData = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameter(); //to get the params for *test*
    String suiteData = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getXmlSuite().getParameters(); //to get the params for *suite*
.... other data to be added to the test
}
```

**In your Test class** :

```
@Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "LoginData",dataProviderClass=XYZ.class)
public static void testLogin(String param)   // arguments vary based on what data providers return
{
```